# Op Amp Tutorial Pspice missing value

Tags: operational-amplifier, pspice

I have this code below for a Amp Op Tutorial from this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3qE3gL7XbT4.  I get the error below for missing value but unsure what is the problem.  I'm new to pspice, so how do I get the simulation to operate correctly?

```
(ExpressProject "OpAmpInv"
  (ProjectVersion "19981106")
  (ProjectType "Analog or A/D Mixed Mode")
  (Folder "Design Resources"
    (Folder "Library")
    (NoModify)
    (BuildFileAddedOrDeleted "x")
    (CompileFileAddedOrDeleted "x")
    (File ".\opampinv.dsn"
      (Type "Schematic Design")))
  (Folder "Outputs")
  (Folder "Referenced Projects")
  (PartMRUSelector
    (0
      (LibraryName
         "C:\PROGRAM FILES\CADENCE\SPB_17.2\TOOLS\CAPTURE\LIBRARY\CAPSYM.OLB")
      (DeviceIndex "0"))
    (VCC
      (LibraryName
         "C:\PROGRAM FILES\CADENCE\SPB_17.2\TOOLS\CAPTURE\LIBRARY\CAPSYM.OLB")
      (DeviceIndex "0"))
    (GND
      (LibraryName
         "C:\PROGRAM FILES\CADENCE\SPB_17.2\TOOLS\CAPTURE\LIBRARY\CAPSYM.OLB")
      (DeviceIndex "0"))
    (VDC
      (FullPartName "VDC.Normal")
      (LibraryName
         "C:\PROGRAM FILES\CADENCE\SPB_17.2\TOOLS\CAPTURE\LIBRARY\PSPICE\SOURCE.OLB")
      (DeviceIndex "0"))
    (VSIN
      (FullPartName "VSIN.Normal")
      (LibraryName
         "C:\PROGRAM FILES\CADENCE\SPB_17.2\TOOLS\CAPTURE\LIBRARY\PSPICE\SOURCE.OLB")
      (DeviceIndex "0"))
    (SOURCE VOLTAGE
      (FullPartName "SOURCE VOLTAGE.Normal")
      (LibraryName
         "C:\PROGRAM FILES\CADENCE\SPB_17.2\TOOLS\CAPTURE\LIBRARY\DISCRETE.OLB")
      (DeviceIndex "0"))
    (R
      (FullPartName "R.Normal")
      (LibraryName
         "C:\PROGRAM FILES\CADENCE\SPB_17.2\TOOLS\CAPTURE\LIBRARY\DISCRETE.OLB")
      (DeviceIndex "0"))
    (RESISTOR
      (FullPartName "RESISTOR.Normal")
      (LibraryName
         "C:\PROGRAM FILES\CADENCE\SPB_17.2\TOOLS\CAPTURE\LIBRARY\DISCRETE.OLB")
      (DeviceIndex "0"))
    (LM741
      (FullPartName "LM741.Normal")
      (LibraryName
         "C:\PROGRAM FILES\CADENCE\SPB_17.2\TOOLS\CAPTURE\LIBRARY\OPAMP.OLB")
      (DeviceIndex "0")))
  (LastUsedLibraryBrowseDirectory
     "C:\Program Files\Cadence\SPB_17.2\tools\capture\library\pspice")
  (MPSSessionName "Ryan W")
  (GlobalState
    (FileView
      (Path "Design Resources")
      (Select "Design Resources"))
    (HierarchyView)
    (Doc
      (Type "COrCapturePMDoc")
      (Frame
        (Placement "44 0 1 -1 -1 -8 -31 0 200 0 150"))
      (Tab 0))
    (Doc
      (Type "COrSchematicDoc")
      (Frame
        (Placement "44 2 3 -1 -1 -8 -31 52 579 52 239")
        (Scroll "339 315")
        (Zoom "200")
        (Occurrence "/"))
      (Path
         "C:\USERS\RYAN W\DOCUMENTS\EDUCATION\COMPUTER PROGRAMMING\PSPICE\TUTORIALS\OPAMPINVTUT\OPAMPINV.DSN")
      (Schematic "SCHEMATIC1")
      (Page "PAGE1"))))



**** INCLUDING SCHEMATIC1.net ****
* source OPAMPINV
R_R3         VO 0 1k
V_V1         VI 0  AC <AC>
-----------------------$
ERROR(ORPSIM-16492): Missing value
+SIN 0 500m 1k 0 0 0
V_V2         V+ 0 12Vdc
V_V3         0 V- 12Vdc
R_R4         N00303 VO 10k
R_R5         VI N00303 1k

**** RESUMING demo1.cir ****
.END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is actually very clear and specific. The actual error is two lines above the message itself. The dollar sign in the line above the message is aligned underneath the missing parameter...you need to specify the ac voltage magnitude for voltage source V1.